# Web requests delayed. DNS issue? IPV6?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipv6

When I try to do a wget of http://www.google.com on my Raspberry Pi, I don't get a response for over 6 seconds, almost all of which is while the output below is stuck on "Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)..."

```
$ time wget http://www.google.com
--2016-12-09 16:39:57--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 74.125.68.103, 74.125.68.99, 74.125.68.105, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|74.125.68.103|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                                            [ <=>                                                                                                           ]  10.67K  --.-KB/s   in 0.009s 

2016-12-09 16:40:03 (1.13 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [10922]


real    0m5.707s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.020s
```

This suggests a DNS problem.  I tried to troubleshoot this by adding a timeout to my /etc/resolv.conf, and commenting out my local 192.168.1.1 server, but it makes no difference in the delays:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by resolvconf
option timeout: 5
domain domain_not_set.invalid
#nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 4.2.2.2
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

When I try to do a nslookup by itself, it comes back without delay.  See below.

What possibly could be going wrong?

```
$ time nslookup www.google.com
Server:     4.2.2.2
Address:    4.2.2.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.200.105
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.200.103
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.200.104
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.200.106
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.200.147
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.200.99


real    0m0.063s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.000s
```

**EDIT:** Rebooting my home router makes no difference.  And other clients on the network (e.g. my MacBook Pro and my mobile phone) have no similar delays when browsing the web.

**EDIT:** I found a kludge that fixes this by installing `sudo apt-get install bind9` and then adding `nameserver 127.0.0.1` to the top of /etc/resolv.conf.  I found this suggestion at [this link](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~comech/tools/linux-slow-dns-lookup/), which suggests this is an IPV6 issue.  However, this is not a good solution, because each time I reboot, my /etc/resolv.conf gets regenerated, my added line gets removed, and my problem returns.  I tried adding 127.0.0.1 to /etc/network/interfaces with `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 127.0.0.1` but that makes the other nameservers disappear upon networking restart.

Comment: When I try that `wget...` I get a `302 Found` redirect to www.google.co.uk. I wonder if the reason getting your web page is slow is because your IP address doesn't have a GeoIP lookup so Google doesn't know where (or if) to redirect you. It might be worth trying the `whois {your_ip_address}` game. (For an IP address of 1.2.3.4 you'd try `whois 1.2.3.4`. If you don't get a sensible answer then try `whois 1.2.3.0`. If that's nonsense try `whois 1.2.0.0`.) On the other hand I don't see why that should delay the lookup six seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `nameserver 4.2.2.2` from your list of domain servers.

Unless you're a Level 3 customer, in which you case you need to contact them directly to ask why name resolution is slow.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately, commenting out 4.2.2.2 from my /etc/resolv.conf does not change the resolution delay when using wget, although it does change the server used when I use nslookup:  `$ time nslookup www.google.com Server: 8.8.8.8 Address: 8.8.8.8#53 Non-authoritative answer: Name: www.google.com Address: 216.58.217.132 real 0m0.071s user 0m0.030s sys 0m0.000s`